# How to set value of data in the firebase real time data base?

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I try to refresh the value of a variable in my data base. But the fonctions `.set()` need two arguments and I don't understand what is the fisrt.

I try to use the `.push()` fonction but this create a new line in my data base. I d'ont want that. I want the value change.

So I know i need to use the `.set()` function but she take two arguments item: Firebase operation and data

What is the first ?

```js
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => { // ajoute des tacoPoint 
          this.test = this.afDatabase.list(`TacoPoint/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();

          this.test.forEach(data => { // ajoute des tacoPoint 
            data.forEach(e => {


              e.Tacopoint = e.Tacopoint + 20;
              console.log(e);

            })
          })
        })

        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
         this.afDatabase.list(`TacoPoint/${auth.uid}`).set(); // need to set the new TacoPoint in the data base 

        })
```

Comment: are you using firebase or firestore?

Comment: I use firebase (real time data base)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I succeeded to use the `.set()` 
We just need to do a reference at the object in the data base like that :

```js
const a = this.afDatabase.object(`TacoPoint/${data.uid}`) // reference 

a.set(/*some data*/) // now you can use the set function
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to set object `data` ,

```
this.afDatabase.collection("TacoPoint").doc(auth.uid).set(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for fast anwser but .collection doesn't exist on Angular Fire module ^^

Comment: import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

Comment: I import in the app Module and the page but doesn't work maybe need to install ?

Comment: Yes, you can refer this. It had CRUD Operation with firebase. https://github.com/AdritaS/Angular-Firebase/blob/master/src/app/employee/employee.service.ts